# CUDA on GeForce 8600GT

Tags: nvidia-geforce, cuda

I have got the cuda driver, toolkit and sdk installed in Ubuntu 10.04. I'm using nVidia Geforce 8600 GT card. Official website says my card is CUDA supported. But on running the deviceQuery that comes with the cuda sdk, I'm getting the following output.

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

There is no device supporting CUDA

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 134566327, CUDA Runtime Version = 0.0, NumDevs = 0


PASSED

Press <Enter> to Quit...
```

Moreover, while booting, I'm getting the following error.
    Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode

```
The following error was encountered. You may need to update your configuration to solve this.

(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module.
Please check you
(EE) NVIDIA:   system's kernel log for additional error messages.
(EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
(EE) No drivers available.
```

But, when I restart X, it boots perfectly.

And, glxinfo gives the following output.

```
name of display: :1.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1.0".
3 GLXFBConfigs:
   visual  x  bf lv rg d st colorbuffer ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
 id dep cl sp sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Segmentation fault
```

So, is GeForce 8600GT actually not CUDA supported, or is the problem with something else? Thanks.

Comment: Have you run `nvidia-settings` to ensure that your driver was installed? What version of the driver did you install (195.36.24?) and what version of CUDA (3.0?)?

Comment: I'm using 195.36.15 driver and CUDA 3.0. Running nvidia-settings produced "You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server." I did just that, but the problem persists.

I have also edited my question to add more info on the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. There is a good way to install the nvidia driver correctly and the avoid problems later. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036788) is a great howto, step-by-step, easy-to-use.

But let me correct it out, regarding the 10.04 release !
First of all (before steps), download the "dkms" pack from the bottom of the post on the linked page, and the nvidia driver from nvidia.com into your home directory.
Step1, remove the drivers. Fix the "180" to "190" or "195" , don't sure how Ubuntu calls it at the minutre.
At step 2, edit `/etc/blacklist.d/blacklist.conf` . Add 2 new entries to the end:
`blacklist nv`
`blacklist nouveau`

Then do a reboot, at the boot menu, select recovery mode. Go with the "root mode with networking" (or what, its at the bottom, you will be able to identify it, don't worry about the instructions. :))

When it boots, type your root password. Then type: `init 3` . Login again (yay).

Now, install the driver with `sudo sh ./NV*` . There will be an error about "distributor provided.." don't care about it, just agree, yes yes (more, grep, fsck :)).

After it finishes, do a `sudo nvidia-xconfig` . THEN, do the `sudo sh ./installdkms*` part. After it finishes, you are done, reboot.

---

Yeah I'm aware of the howto and how its 'harder' than the "install restricted  modules". However, a lot of people noticed issues , anomalies with the default driver. This way you will get the NVidia binary driver, more recent than the one Ubuntu ships, and it won't be a problem during kernel upgrades. Also, you can upgrade the driver by hand whenever you want.  If you get stuck, comment, ask. (Check which part seems to be hard , check if you can find that blacklist and such before you dive in.)

---

And yeah, after this, we'll continue with the CUDA stuff. :)

Comment: In my case, I had to run `sudo sh ./NV* -k $(uname -r)` in order for it to properly install kernel modules and not hang at that part of the installation.

Comment: That can happen if you dont run the latest kernel installed. In that case, try regenerating your grub config (`sudo update-grub`) , do a reboot, fire up the latest kernel and try reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the steps and installed the devdriver 195.36.15. But after booting, my screen resolution has gone really low, and in nvidia-settings X server display configuration, I can't find any resolution higher than 640x480. And, I have not yet proceeded with the cuda toolkit installation.

Comment: Installed the toolkit and the SDK. The code samples work perfectly, thanks a lot for your help. Now the only problem is the resolution, which does not go above 640x480. Any help regarding that is much appreciated.

Comment: Okay. Did you do the `sudo nvidia-xconfig` part? If yes, type `sudo nvidia-settings` into a terminal and set it higher. It HAVE to go higher if you have a correctly working NVidia driver.

Comment: FIX: `sudo nano -w /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` . Write the 'blacklist' lines there. (Darn. How comes nobody notices such a mistake?)

Comment: Yes, I had already blacklisted nv and nouveau in the blacklist.conf file. And, I had also tried changing the resolution in nvidia-settings, but I was not provided with any resolution higher than 640x480. Later I figured it out myself that the HorizSync and VertRefresh values in xorg.conf weren't matching with those of my monitor. Once I changed them, the resolution problem got fixed. Thanks anyway.